# Error when installing PySide on Nvidia Jetson Nano 4gb

Tags: qt, cmake, pip, pyside, nvidia

This is the error that shows up when I try to run "pip install PySide" on my Jetson Nano. Can someone please let me know how I can fix this error?

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:620 (message):
  /usr/bin/qmake reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu" but
  QtCore could not be found there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the
  target build environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2.6")
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found suitable version "2.9.4", minimum required is "2.6.32")
-- Could NOT find LibXslt (missing: LIBXSLT_LIBRARIES LIBXSLT_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.1.19")
Qt QTGUI library not found.
Qt QTXML library not found.
Qt QTCORE library not found.
CMake Error at ApiExtractor/CMakeLists.txt:82 (qt4_add_resources):
  Unknown CMake command "qt4_add_resources".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/pip-build-mimaL7/PySide/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.7-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
error: Error configuring shiboken
```

Comment: Being you I would concentrate on the first warning, would check whether directory `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` actually contains QtCore library and if not - would try to fix the Qt installation.

Answer (score 0):

PySide does not have official release package for ARM systems. You have to build it yourself. All I can afford is [this .whl](https://github.com/ISPlatonov/PySide2_for_Nvidia_Jetson_whl), but keep in mind that it was built on Ubuntu 20.04 with JetPack 4 and Python 3.6 on board.